# 3D Flip Multiple Cards at Once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make sense of the 3D card animation flipping feature found on the article here: http://callmenick.com/post/css-transitions-transforms-animations-flipping-card

but I can't figure out how to flip 2 cards at once on click. For instance, if I click on the first card, I would also like to simultaneously flip the second card, as well.

HTML:

```
<div class="card effect__click">
  <div class="card__front">
    <span class="card__text">front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card__back">
    <span class="card__text">back</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.card__front,
.card__back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card__front,
.card__back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.9s;
          transition: transform 0.9s;
}
.card__text{color:#fff;}
.card__front {
  background-color: #ff5078;
}

.card__back {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card.effect__hover:hover .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.effect__hover:hover .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateY(0);
}
.card.effect__click.flipped .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.effect__click.flipped .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.effect__click");
  for ( var i  = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var card = cards[i];
    clickListener(card);
  }

  function clickListener(card) {
    card.addEventListener( "click", function() {
      var c = this.classList;
      c.contains("flipped") === true ? c.remove("flipped") : c.add("flipped");
    });
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either [`querySelector[All]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for next elements using [`:nth-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector or other suitable one or use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling):

```js
(function() {
  var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.effect__click");
  for ( var i  = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var card = cards[i];
    clickListener(card);
  }
  
  function flip(card){
    if (!card) return;
    var c = card.classList;
      c.contains("flipped") === true ? c.remove("flipped") : c.add("flipped");
    }

  function clickListener(card) {
    card.addEventListener( "click", function() {
      flip(this);
      flip(this.nextElementSibling);
    });
  }
})();
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.card__front,
.card__back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card__front,
.card__back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.9s;
          transition: transform 0.9s;
}
.card__text{color:#fff;}
.card__front {
  background-color: #ff5078;
}

.card__back {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card.effect__hover:hover .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.effect__hover:hover .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateY(0);
}
.card.effect__click.flipped .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.effect__click.flipped .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="card effect__click">
  <div class="card__front">
    <span class="card__text">front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card__back">
    <span class="card__text">back</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card effect__click">
  <div class="card__front">
    <span class="card__text">front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card__back">
    <span class="card__text">back</span>
  </div>
</div>
```